# Custom Quote Sync appexchange for syncing custom fields between quote line item and opportunity line item

Tags: appexchange, opportunity-lineitem, quotelineitem

I installed the Custom Quote Sync appechange, wich synchronize the custom fields between quote line item and opportunity line item. But It seems it doesnt work if there are any validation rules on QLI Or OLI.

Any solution for that ?

Comment: Best bet would be to contact the vendor.

Comment: I did, but no answer!

Comment: Is it a freebie and which specific App is it (link would be a good idea)?